# Can GCov be used in windows?

Tags: gcov

Can I install gcov tool in windows?
Or can I take plug-in of this tool in eclipse in windows?
I am very new to this tool. I don't have any idea about this tool. Please help me to get the information of this tool.
please tell me the requirements to run this tool on my machine.

Where can I get more information about gcov and also please provide a link from where I can **download** this tool.

**Does gcov tool accepts only c/c++ files or it also takes header files(*.h) as input?**

Comment: Did the provided answer from valbok "worked for you"? If yes: please accept it as working answer, if there's something unclear add this in its comment and I'll try to add the missing bits. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

> Can I install gcov tool in windows?

Yes. We use gcc to build QNX projects in Windows.

> Where can I get more information about gcov and also pls provide a link from where I can download this tool.

gcov is a part [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html),

> Does gcov tool accepts only c/c++ files or it also takes header files(*.h) as input?

gcov accepts cpp, and h too

Answer (score 1):

gcov is part of the [gcc tools](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/).  If you are building and linking with gcc on Windows (which is fairly unusual), you could use it.  Since it is part of the compiler, you cannot add it as a plugin to your IDE, though there are probably plugins that allow you to interact with the data that it produces.

It sounds to me like you need to figure out what you are trying to do. gperftools or valgrind might be better suited to your needs.

Comment: I got the gcov setup in Ubuntu/Linux, is there a way to tell the gcov viewer plugin in VCode to display the result somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use eclipse CDT. It has built in [gcov plugin](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.linuxtools.gcov.docs%2FLinux_Tools_Project%2FGCov%2FUser_Guide%2FInstallation-and-Set-Up.html).