# Code coverage in Qt Creator using MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mingw

How to generate and view code coverage using **Qt Creator** with **MinGW** on **Windows**?

I'm already able to generate it using [GCOV](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Gcov.html) and [LCOV](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php) on **OS X** with the following flags in my `.pro` file:

```
mac {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += --coverage
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += --coverage
}
```

I have accomplished that by following [this tutorial](https://asmaloney.com/2017/01/code/code-coverage-of-unit-tests-using-qt-5-on-macos/).

What tools/flags should I use to generate and view the code coverage on Windows?

**Note**: on OS X I'm using Clang.

---

**Update**:

I have successfully generated the **GCNO** and **GCDA** files, but I don't know how can I access/visualize the code coverage properly.

As far as I know, **LCOV** doesn't work on Windows.

I found the [Ported to Windows LCOV Code Coverage tool](https://github.com/valbok/lcov) project on Github and I will try to use it.

Some related questions:

[Qt and gcov, coverage files are not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483370/qt-and-gcov-coverage-files-are-not-generated)

[Can GCov be used in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717920/can-gcov-be-used-in-windows)

[Is there any actively supported lcov port for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816981/is-there-any-actively-supported-lcov-port-for-windows)

Comment: You added this to the `mac` section, yet you're running Windows. Why?

Comment: @MrEricSir actually the application is multi platform so I would need to generate the code coverage on both Windows and OS X. Until now I have only followed the tutorial mentioned (for OS X). As I explained, I read that the GCOV doesn't work with MinGW, but I have not tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

For this platform case your .pro file should contain:

```
win32 {
  # MinGW-related settings
}
```